# Replace soil pipe or continue cleaning it annually?

Tags: sewer

Tree roots grow into the house sewage drainage pipe some 6+ feet out of the house.  Each year I have a company clean out the roots with a large drill.  Replacing the pipe will be expensive.  What conditions or symptoms should I take as indications that I need to replace the pipe?

Comment: If you divide the replacement cost by the annual cost you will see how many years it will take to break even - just remember the trees never stop....

Answer (score 2):

If you have roots in your pipe it needs replacing. The cleaning company is just using you as a yearly revenue source. If there is a leak in your waste pipe you are leaking untreated waste into the ground. Not particularly good from an environmental standpoint.

Have a look into pipe burst. These guys actually pull a new pipe through the old one breaking up the old one as it goes.